# Problem FBConnect (IPHONE), code not run on didLoad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fbconnect

Three days ago this code worked...:(

The label will not update to show the loaded facebook username.

```
//Interface .h
IBOutlet UILabel *namefb;  
...
@property(nonatomic, retain)UILabel *namefb;


//Implementation .m

- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {

        NSArray* users = result;

    NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];

       namefb.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Log-in: %@", name];//not update
}
```

(I have also connected the label in IB and imported all fbconnect delegates )

When I run it in debug, the variable name is right, but namefb.text does not get updated..

Any ideas?

sorry for my english..:)

Comment: Don't worry about your english skills. One of us in the community will edit it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes three things:

1. The `result` object is of type `NSArray`.
2. The `NSArray` has at least one object, which is an `NSDictionary`.
3. That object has a key "name" that has an `NSString` object associated with it.

Test each of these three things, perhaps by using some `NSLog()` statements, and you should see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you connected `namefb` to a UILabel object in Interface Builder. Simply making that variable an outlet won't cause an object to appear there out of thin air—you need to create the object (in IB) and plug it into the outlet (in IB).

Until it's connected to an object, the variable will hold `nil`, and a message to `nil` does nothing.